# Excel VBA Script: Run whenever a cell is changed in a column range to activate autofilters on a data set

Tags: vba, excel, loops, autofilter

I know I am a complete noob. But is there a better way to run the below code using loops? 
Please guide me. I have am trying to use autofilter conditions on a range B14:P14 and a big data set. I want the autofilters to trigger is someone makes any changes to the range B14: P14. Its a code to sort out available hours for a list of employees weekly. 
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Range("B14") Then
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("B14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=15, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("C14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("D14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("E14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("F14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("G14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=20, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("H14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("I14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=22, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("J14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=23, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("K14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=24, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("L14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=25, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("M14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=26, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("N14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=27, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("O14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=28, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("P14").Text

Else

If Target = Range("C14") Then
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("B14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=15, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("C14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("D14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("E14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("F14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("G14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=20, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("H14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("I14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=22, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("J14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=23, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("K14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=24, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("L14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=25, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("M14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=26, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("N14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=27, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("O14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=28, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("P14").Text

Else

If Target = Range("D14") Then
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("B14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=15, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("C14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("D14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("E14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("F14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("G14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=20, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("H14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("I14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=22, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("J14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=23, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("K14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=24, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("L14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=25, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("M14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=26, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("N14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=27, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("O14").Text
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter field:=28, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("P14").Text

End if
End if
End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify your first if so you can see an example

```
For i = 1 To 15
    Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(19, 28)).AutoFilter 
    field:=13 + i, Criteria1:=">=" & Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 1 + i)).Text
Next
```

Hope it Helps!